# Discord.py message pinning?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.8

I've tried multiple different ways to pin (I also want to try unpinning it) a certain message (it has already been sent) using a bot / selfbot with discord.py, here a few examples:

```
@pinner.event
async def on_message():
    if message.content == 'message im trying to pin':
    message.pin


@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def pin_message():
    message = ('message id ')
    await message.pin(message id)
```

I'm using Python 3.8 and the latest version of discord.py API.

Answer (score 3):

In order to pin a message you must first have the message, once you have it you can `await message.pin()`

To unpin you can use `await message.unpin()`

The bot must also have `manage_messages` permisson in order to pin or unpin messages.

This would pin the message that the user triggered the command with

```
@bot.command()
async def pin_message(ctx):
  await ctx.message.pin()
```

If you want to pin a specific message you must fetch it with either `ctx.fetch_message(message_id)` or if you have the text channel `textchannel.fetch_message(message_id)`

This will pin a message that the user wants:

```
@bot.command()
async def pin_this(ctx, message_id: int):
  message = await ctx.fetch_message(message_id)
  await message.pin()
```

Optional: You can also specify a reason with `await message.pin(reason="your reason here")`

#### Documentation:

- [discord.Message.pin](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.pin)
- [discord.Message.unpin](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.unpin)
- [discord.Message.unpin](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.unpin)
- [discord.TextChannel.fetch_message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)

Comment: Please review your links in comparison to their labels. I made them consistent but you probably want something else there.

Comment: I was looking for it to be with the on_connect feature, not activated by a command, sorry for the lack of information I gave, for example; I'd start the bot and it'd pin a message like 'I'm online'

Answer (score 0):

For pinning messages, you use:

```
await message.pin(reason=None)
```

For unpinning:

```
await message.unpin(reason=None)
```

From your example:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'message im trying to pin':
        await message.pin()
```

Go to the API: https://docs.pycord.dev/en/master/api.html?highlight=pin#discord.Message.pin for more.

Note that the bot needs Manage Messages to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example:

```
async def pinmessage(ctx, id):
  message = get_message(id)
  pin_message(message)
```

so when I run

```
>pinmessage 12345678901234
```

it will pin that message.